# What's the worst that could happen with while(true)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, while-loop

I'm practicing C++ through Visual C++ Express and tutorials on Youtube. I made a calculator by following a cool video, but I didn't want the program to end right after you do one equation, so I searched for what to do and tried while(true).

The problem is, instead of a number, when the program prompted me to type in a number, I typed in "blah", hit enter, and the program started to just go crazy so I exited real quick.

Without the while(true), if I type in "blah", then the program instantly goes to the "press any button to exit..." phrase. So what I'm wondering is, how dangerous is while(true)?
Also, I'm really sorry if this question is inappropriate-_-

Comment: No code, no answer. The problem is likely totally unrelated to `while(true)`.

Comment: Agreed. while(true) should really not change anything except that it repeats the code over and over again; maybe the wrong type of the data entered leads to problems with your way of reading data.

Comment: You have to validate the input, i.e. for a calculator you have to make sure it is numbers. Besides that, infinite loops can be usefull sometimes.

Comment: ***"I'm really sorry if this question is inappropriate"*** - Question is appropriate, the way you ask is not. Provide some code, describe your problem in details.

Comment: Your personal answer is probably that you should learn a few more basics of C++ and you'll be able to run your own programs with authority in no time. But to be pedantic, a program that contains `while (true) { }` technically exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB, so then technically the worst that could happen is a velociraptor tearing off the OP's head? :-P

Comment: @Kerrek Could you point out where it says that in the standard?  I remember some discussion as to whether the compiler could eliminate it, but that would still just be unspecified, not undefined.  (And of course, I don't think it's relevant here, since the OP almost certainly has code in his loop.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: that means that `while (true);` would be undefined, but from the description I understand that he is reading from `stdin`, and thus complies with the requirements. That would not be UB.

Comment: @KerrekSB The wording of that paragraph is very strange.  I'm not sure that it means undefined behavior; it seems to be simply unspecified if code after the loop will ever execute or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while(true)` can obviously create an "infinite" loop, which just means there's nothing internal to the process capable of causing the loop to terminate.  It's still possible that the Operating System may decide (e.g. after a CPU usage quota is exhausted) or be asked (e.g. `kill -HUP processid` on UNIX/Linux) to terminate the process.

It's worth considering the difference between infinite loops containing:

- blocking (I/O?) requests, such as waits for new network client connections or data or keyboard input, or even just for a specific interval to elapse, then a finite amount of periodic or I/O related processing, and
- non-blocking branching and data-processing instructions that just spin around burning CPU and/or thrashing CPU/memory caches (e.g. `x += array[random(array.size())];`)

The former case may actually be deliberately used in some cases, such as a server process that doesn't need to do any orderly shutdown and can therefore let the OS shut it down without running any post-loop code, but the second case is usually a programming error: you tend to only have such a `while(true)` when there's some way for an exit condition or error occuring during processing controlled by the loop to interrupt the loop.  For example, there may be an `if (condition) break;`, or something that will throw an exception when there's an error.  This may not be obvious - if could for example be an exception from some function that's invoked - even from having set the Standard iostream's functions to throw on conversion failure or EOF - rather than a visible `throw` statement in the source code within the loop.

It's worth noting that many other things can create infinite loops too - for example `while (a < b)` could go forever if there's no conditions under which `a` could become `>= b`.  So, it's a general aspect of programming that you have to consider how your loops exit, and not some problem with the safety of the language.  For inputs, it's normal to do something like:

```
while (std::cin >> my_int)
{
    // can use my_int...
}

// failed to convert next input from stdin to an int and/or hit EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

The worst thing that will happen with `while(true){}` is that you will go into an infinite loop.

If you write something into those brackets other then an instruction that breaks the loop, that will be repeated over and over again.

This answers your question. If you want to know whats wrong with your calculator, create a new question with a specific problem.

Comment: Unless what you have in the brackets is something like `break`, `throw`, `return`, `exit` or `terminate`.

Comment: Any attempt to write an exhaustive list is going to be difficult. There is also `std::quick_exit` in C++11, and I am not sure what `abort` calls exactly under the hood.

Comment: And `longjmp` if you like mixing your C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a console application, you intend it to be run from within a console.

*Don't* `while`, `cin.get()` or anything, just use your program as it's intended to be used.

Comment: downvoting is fine.  But please explain why. Here's my guess: **This Doesn't Answer The Question**.  Maybe I didn't answer the question, but I flagged the underlying problem.